# Search word document and delete found text

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Trying to search a word document through excel VBA and delete the found text:

```
 Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    objWord.Visible = True
    path = "C:\Test.docx"
    txt1 = "Search text"
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(path)


    With objWord.ActiveDocument
        Set myRange = .Content
        With myRange.Find
            .Text = txt1
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Execute

            Selection.Delete

        End With
    End With
```

However, it doesn't seem to delete the text!

Any help please

Comment: What Vityata says... If you were doing `objWord.Selection.Find` (which I don't recomment) then `Selection.Delete` ought to work, as long as `Find` was successful - otherwise something else would be deleted. `myRange.Delete` would also work, as long as you test whether `Find.Execute` returns True. So on the whole, Vityata's suggestion is the best way.

Comment: @CindyMeister Could you give an example with the delete? I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Looking at your comment to Vityata: What do you mean by "line"? An empty paragraph? What you search is standing in its own paragraph and deleting it leaves the paragraph? Then try searchig `txt1 & ^p`

Comment: @CindyMeister Yes exactly that, it leaves the paragraph. Your fix worked - thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

`Selection.Delete` works pretty well - it deletes the selected text. In your case, you are not selecting anything, thus nothing is deleted.

Try to execute the replacement like this:

```
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(path)
With objDoc.Content.Find
    .Text = txt1
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True
End With
```

[MSDN Finding and Replacing Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211953(v=office.11).aspx)

Comment: Still unfortunately not doing anything. I found a solution online which uses:    With objWord.ActiveDocument
        Set myRange = .Content
        With myRange.Find
            .Execute FindText:=txt1, replacewith:="", Replace:=1
            .Execute FindText:=txt2, replacewith:="", Replace:=1
        End With
    End With However it leaves a line when replacing the text - I need to remove it as the line messes up the process later down in my process